# Force images to be next to each other

Tags: html, image

I have 4 images that I want next to each other no matter what. But when the windows is not wide enough the overflowing images are in the next line. How can I prevent that?
I tried "inline", "inline-block" and even "inline-table" but it happens everytime.
The images width aren't fixed, they depend on the height of the window, so setting a min-width is not possible.
And I don't want to put them together to a single image.

Thank you for your help
Julian

Comment: show your code. use jsfiddle.net

Comment: It's just four <img> tags with the display style set to inline

Comment: 1. Set width percetage wise based on window size. 2. Put all images inside one DIV and set the width in this DIV. So, if if the window is smaller then images it will show the scroll in the window.

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/T7r72/ try resize the preview section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap them in a div and give the div a min-width of the sum of the images' widths.

Comment: I forgot to say the with is set to auto, so it depends ont he height